# Can I Turn Off Implicit Navigation in Jsf 2.0?

Tags: jsf, migration, jsf-2, navigation

I'm migrating old projects from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0.
The projects are JSP based.

I'm having trouble with implicit navigation after the migration.
The action methods that return values (Let's say, for internal use) cause JSF to try to navigate to non existing pages.

For example, a method that return `"Error"` will make the browser try to access `/Error.jsp` which will result in a 404.

I would like, for these projects, to turn off implicit navigation.
Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. It's however planned for JSF 2.2, see also [JSF spec issue 937](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-937).

What is it, the internal use for which you're trying to (ab?)use navigation outcomes? Exception handling? You might want to throw a normal exception instead and handle it the usual way.

Comment: :-) I'm just trying to run a backing bean method that has no effect. As far as I know the action method signature has to be a `String` return value.
The `"Error"` example could have been `"Success"` for that matter. I want a method that runs, does something, and then the app continues without navigation.
Should I just return null if I want to avoid navigation?

Comment: Yes definitely you need to return `null` if you don't want navigation. Or just declare the method `void` if you don't want to navigate at all.

Comment: Great. Thanks. Just wanted to make sure i'm not doing something that would cause problems later.